# Cannot run PS1 with different credential

Tags: powershell, credentials

I have a script, which does multiple things on different servers. If I log on to a computer with my admin account, the script runs fine. However, I want to to be able to run it on my standard account by using my admin credential.

I have used invoke-command with -credential or get-credential at the beginning of my script but none has worked. I keep getting "access is denied"

Here is a part of my script.

```
$Computername = "Computer"
if (test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count 1 -quiet) {Write-Host "`n$computername is ONLINE."} 
else {Write-Host "`n$computername is OFFLINE."

    Get-ADComputer -identity $computername
        if (!$?) {Write-Host "`n$computername is not found in ActiveDir."}
        Else {
             $dom = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()

             $root = $dom.GetDirectoryEntry()

             $search = [System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]$root

             $search.filter = "(&(objectclass=computer)(name=$computername))" 

             $search.findall() | %{$_.GetDirectoryEntry() } | %{$_.DeleteObject(0)} 

             Write-Host "`n$computername is deleted from ActiveDir."
    }}
```

Comment: "*I have used invoke-command with -credential or get-credential at the beginning of my script*" - Can you include that code? If you're invoking it on your computer,  instead of on a domain controller, you might be running into double-hop authentication issues where it's not allowed to pass your admin credentials to the domain controller. (Why aren't you using `$c = Get-ADComputer; $c | Remove-ADComputer` instead of all the searching?)

Comment: Is your 'standard' account is a part of domain? i.e. its a domain user account or just local computer account?

Comment: In this case i would try something like ` Start-Process Powershell.exe -Argumentlist MyScript.ps1 -credential Domain\User -Workingdirectory c:\ `

Comment: Thanks Restless. It works